# Find jpg images without an extra webp suffix

Tags: bash, shell, find, batch-processing, webp

I have a directory with a few million images randomly placed inside other subdirectories.
I want to generate webp images for all jpg images by appending the webp extension, leaving alone other formats such as gif images.

I can run the command below on ubuntu 18 to generate all the webp images I want, consisting of the file name with .webp suffix appended to it:

```
find /home/photos -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg \) | parallel -eta cwebp {} -o {}.webp
```

However, in time I'll add other jpg images to some other subdirectories and I want to run the same command again, only for the new jpg images that have no .webp suffix equivalent.

If I have:

```
-- 1.png
-- 1.gif
-- 2.jpg
-- 2.jpg.webp
-- 3.jpg
-- subdir/4.jpg
-- subdir/5.jpg
-- subdir/5.jpg.webp
```

How do I find, `3.jpg` and `subdir/4.jpg` only? (the ones without a webp version)

Furthermore, searching by time is not possible because the new photos may have an older modification time than the last run.

Comment: Use `touch` to make a file called `LastRunTimeSentinel`, then when you run `find` again, look only for files newer than that file.

Comment: The dates are not an option, because these can be old photos with modification dates from several years ago that I find and add back to the directory. Running on newer than date, won't work on those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test for existence of the output file within `parallel` and only create it if it doesn't exist like this:

```
find . -iname \*.jpg | parallel -eta 'out={}.webp; [ ! -f "$out" ] && cwebp {} -o "$out"'
```

Or, exactly the same, but trying harder to be less negative in my outlook:

```
find . -iname \*.jpg | parallel -eta 'out={}.webp; [ -f "$out" ] || cwebp {} -o "$out"'
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

To list only files that have no corresponding `.webp` file you could use `grep` as follows:

```
find /home/photos -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg \) |
grep -vFxf <(find /home/photos -type f -name \*.webp | sed 's/\.webp$//')
```

Check the output, then append `| parallel ...`

With `<(...)` we create an anonymous file that contains all `.jpg` files that already have a corresponding `.webp` file. `grep` filters out all of these lines from stdin.

This approach will not work for paths with line breaks in them. But since you didn't use `-print0` in the first place, that doesn't seem to be a problem.